# No puedo redondear los decimales en Python por el error type complex doesn't define round method

Tags: python

No sé si estoy colocando mal cómo redondearlo, pero me sale

> TypeError: type complex doesn't define round method

```
from cmath import sqrt
    
base=int(input("Base: "))
altura_prisma=int(input("Altura del prisma: "))
    
altura_triangulo = sqrt(base**2-(base/2)**2)
area_triangulo = (base*altura_triangulo)/2
    
volumen = altura_prisma*area_triangulo
volumen = round(volumen,4)
print(volumen, " cm^3")
```

Leí en otros lugares que decía que era porque es un número complejo, pero no sé.

Comment: Imprime el volumen sin redondear a ver qué sale. Parecería a priori que la raíz cuadrada te está devolviendo un número imaginario, pero no entiendo por qué. Que datos de entrada estás probando?

Comment: Ah, espera, ya lo he visto. Estás usando el sqrt de cmath en vez del de math. El que usas es para números complejos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas importando `cmath`, que es para matemática con números complejos.

Debes importar `math`

```
from math import sqrt

base = int(input("Base: "))
altura_prisma = int(input("Altura del prisma: "))

altura_triangulo = sqrt(base ** 2 - (base / 2) ** 2)
area_triangulo = (base * altura_triangulo) / 2

volumen = altura_prisma * area_triangulo
volumen = round(volumen, 4)
print(volumen, " cm^3")
```

produce

```
Base: 5
Altura del prisma: 10
108.2532  cm^3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si estabas usando números complejos por error o porque lo necesitabas. Normalmente, los *redondeos de números complejos* se hacen para que queden más concisos a la hora de mostrarlos. Para ello lo mejor es *"formatear"* el número mediante una [cadena de formato](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```py
volumen = altura_prisma*area_triangulo
# volumen = round(volumen,4)
print(f"{volumen:.4f} cm^3")
```